Low Energy Pion (Spin 0) and Nucleon (Spin 1/2) Scattering phases
I am currently trying to understand how two body scattering, in particular the pion-nucleon scattering, works. I have seen various papers about this scattering process online, such as this one, but all of these seem to use quantum field theory, which I do not really know. Therefore, I decided to approach the (low energy version of) problem by using non-relativistic quantum mechanics. Chapter 6.4 of Sakurai's quantum mechanics discusses scattering in the context of partial waves and scattering phases but does so in the context of single particle scattering. How would I calculate the scattering phases for a pion-nucleon scattering at low energies?
